# Multiple references to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pointers, reference

Is there any way for a variable to act as a reference to another variable? Could I have multiples variable all hold the same information regarding a single piece of data?

For example:

```
var foo = "data";
var bar = foo;

// I want this to set both foo & bar to null
foo = null;

console.log(bar); // However, bar is still set to "data"
```

In `C` or `C++` you're able to get this desired behavior with pointers; having two variables reference the same location in memory.

Is there some way to mimic this behavior in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think you get your desired behavior in C/C++ either. If you set pointer `b` to some non-`null` pointer `a` and then set `a` to `null`, pointer `b` will still point to the non-`null` place in memory. (That's not to say that you can't get the desired behavior in C++ with pointer references.)

Comment: @TedHopp What I meant was if `foo` was an `Obj*` and `bar` was also an `Obj*` and they both pointed to the same `Obj`, if `foo` or `bar` changed their `Obj` value then the update would appear to both variables.

Comment: Well, yes. That happens in JavaScript as well. However, the code you posted would do nothing like that in C (if you changed `var` to `char *`).

Comment: @TedHopp Correct, hence my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, variables that have objects as their value are actually scalar references (pointers) to objects, so assignment simply copies object references, not the objects themselves.  So when you do

`var bar = foo;`

the value of `foo` gets copied.  This means both `foo` and `bar` have *copies* of the same value.

Even with objects, this won't work

```
var x = {};
var y = x; // y and x both point to the same object
x = null;
// y still points to the object
```

Again, `x` and `y` are copies of the reference, so both `x` and `y` are separate references, each with the same value.  But nulling one out does nothing to do the other.

The closest you can get is what @Derek朕會功夫 said, which is to do

```
var x = {val: 'data'};
var y = x;
delete x.val;
// y.val is now undefined
```

And pass `x` or `y` around.

Comment: +1 for a substantially correct answer, but pass-by-value semantics has nothing to do with this, since nothing is being passed (no function calls are involved).

Comment: Ah okay; it's too bad JavaScript doesn't have an easy way to do this. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @TedHopp ah yes, I see.  Is there a special name for reference values being copied on assignment?

Comment: I'm not aware of any special name for the assignment of reference values—or for assignment of any other scalar value, for that matter,

Comment: @TedHopp hmm what should the answer read then?  "uses pass by value semantics when assigning variable values"?

Comment: I'd say something like "In JavaScript, variables that have objects as their value are actually scalar references (pointers) to objects, so assignment simply copies object references, not the objects themselves." Wordy, but clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sorta. Object references are similar to pointers in C:

```
var foo = {value: "data"};
var bar = foo;

foo.value = undefined;
console.log("Value: %s", bar.value);  // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. If the value is a primitive, the value is copied, and if it's an object the reference is copied.

The only thing you can do is point multiple variables to the same object. However reassigning either variable will not re-assign the other.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of different variables types in JavaScript: primitive and reference. Have a look at this article, section Primitive Types and Reference Types explains it really well https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/ch04.html