# How to change the value of the variable within another variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know, in JavaScript, if is possible to change value of the variable within another variable.

```
var a;
a= 0;
b= a;
b= 1;

alert(a);
```

Why output of `var a` is `0` ? How can I have like output `1` ?

if **b == a** why when i change value of `b` doesn't change even value of `var a` ?

Comment: Not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: when you do `b = a` the *value* of a is copied into b. They dont refer to the same memory location.

Comment: Primitive types are passed by value in JavaScript. You would be looking for passing by reference. Here's a discussion on the topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686990/javascript-variable-reference-alias

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344365/multiple-references-to-a-variable-in-javascript